# White page that appears before app home view

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have developed Ionic2 app and published it into Google Play store.All are working fine except one issue.The issue is, it shows a white page that appears before app home view.Can you tell me how to solve this issue?

Please see the [**Video**](https://youtu.be/Knixjeld4LY).

**Note:** On dev environment where there is no such issue.This issue is Only on the published version.

Hope it is related with the splash screen.Which one should I change?

**config.xml**

```
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

Comment: Nice video, it's good to see a visual explanation.  Is your app performing a lot of work in the "home view" activitie's onCreate? Make sure you load the layout/view first then perform long operations in the background afterwards.  Also, the white background is probably the app theme.  You can set the window background color in `styles.xml`.

Comment: Thanks :) No it is just a login page.I cannot see any `styles.xml` file.can you tell me what is the path of that file? I'm looking at my dev folder.I'm using Ionic2 CLI to generate project @CzarMatt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you're using the `--prod --release` flags when building the apk (just to make sure you're not using the dev apk).

The issue may be also related to the splash screen being hidden before the platform is ready, so please make sure you have this configs in your `config.xml` file:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
```

And then in your `app.component.ts` file hide the splash screen manually like this:

```
import { Platform, ...} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Splashscreen, ... } from 'ionic-native';

//...

constructor(): {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        Splashscreen.hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This white page probably is the window background of the app.

You can set your color in `styles.xml` with `windowBackground` in your app theme.

This is to resolve the color, but if you want to remove the time between views, please put your code. You should start the new activity and in this activity `onCreate()`, the first thing use the `setContentView()` method.

Comment: I cannot see any `styles.xml` file.can you tell me what is the path of that file? I'm looking at my dev folder.I have used Ionic2 CLI to generate a project.